# Não estou conseguindo obter um provider para Oracle com Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle, code-first

Estou fazendo o seguinte:

Pasta Model dou Add > New Item segue imagens
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então seleciono ADO.Net Entity, dou um nome e ADD
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seleciono Code First e dou Next
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bem nesse passo, seleciono , e vejam pela imagem que não tenho a opção do Oracle Client e eu já adicionei na referência do projeto. Como eu faço a partir daí para poder trabalhar com o Oracle?

Faltou um detalhe: Eu já criei a conexão com o Oracle em Servers Explorer e testei e está ok.

Segui os passos do colega Morrison e quando vou setar minha conexão, agora dá esse erro. O que mais tenho que fazer, para resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja aqui como estou fazendo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resolvi a questão do erro postado, era o tnsnames que estava errado, e agora está dando esse outro erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui, http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm as versões são diferentes, vê se você fez as etapas corretamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta é a maneira terrivelmente difícil de trabalhar com o driver da Oracle dentro do ASP.NET MVC.

A maneira fácil é instalando [o pacote NuGet oficial do Oracle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/). Há duas maneiras de fazer:

1. No Visual Studio, vá em Tools > Extensions and Updates > Procure o pacote por lá. Não recomendo esta porque algumas vezes o pacote não aparece;
2. No Visual Studio, vá em View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console e digite nele:

   ```
   PM> Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework
   ```

Feito isto, abra seu Web.config e localize a tag `<entityFramework>`. Se houver, substitua a tag toda pelo seguinte:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Se não houver, coloque o conteúdo acima antes de `</configuration>`.

Feito isto, seu projeto está pronto para funcionar com Entity Framework e Oracle.

---

**EDIT**

Como você quer o ADO.NET Entity Data Model Wizard, você precisará instalar o adaptador para a IDE que permita você usar o Oracle no Wizard: o Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio.

[Você pode baixá-lo aqui](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Fiz todos esses passos que você mencionou em seu post, mas mesmo assim não consigo um provider para o oracle usando EF Code First, ou seja, nos passos que coloquei no post. Continua não aparecendo nada.

Comment: Você quer mesmo usar o ADO.NET Entity Data Model? Ok, eu expando a resposta.

Comment: Então foi o que me apereceu em uma consulta à internet que fiz, mas estou aberto a sugestão para melhor. O que eu estou fazendo, é apenas uma POC para demonstrar aos superiores o uso do ReportViewer, em lugar do jasper report, dado os problemas apresentados por ele(TomCat).

Comment: Então, mas este jeito de montar uma base pelo Code First está deixando de ser usado, mas ok, coloquei um link para você na resposta. Veja agora.

Comment: Acho que eu preciso mudar minha abordagem. Não deu certo, instalei esse patch que você me indicou e continua não tendo provider. Vou pesquisar uma outra forma de trabalhar com Oracle no Entity, mesmo assim, obrigado.

Comment: Acho que faltou o ODAC. Vou instalar e ver o que acontece. De qualquer forma, estou aberto a idéias. Vou abrir outro post sobre o assunto, de qual melhor caminho para trabalhar com Entity e Oracle.